# Is a custom role provider in ASP.Net instantiated for every user using Windows Authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've written a custom Role Provider for ASP.Net MVC. I'm calling a WCF service to get the roles to authorize the current user. I'm using Windows Authentication.

I want to store the current users roles in a variable for the role provider class but am unclear if the class is created per session, or per application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's instantiated once.  A quick look at the docs confirmed this:

> For each role provider specified in
>   the configuration for an application,
>   ASP.NET instantiates a single
>   role-provider instance that is used
>   for all of the requests served by an 
>   HttpApplication object. As a result,
>   you can have multiple requests
>   executing concurrently. ASP.NET does
>   not ensure the thread safety of calls
>   to your provider. You will need to
>   write your provider code to be thread
>   safe. For example, creating a
>   connection to a database or opening a
>   file for editing should be done within
>   the member that is called, such as 
>   AddUsersToRoles , rather than opening
>   a file or database connection when the
>   Initialize method is called.

Comment: Thanks. I added the roles per session so as to not call the service for each GetRolesForUser(string userName);

Answer (score 0):

per application